# Is there an easy solution to find a result depending on 3 data?

Tags: javascript, logic

I would like to know if there is an "easy" solution in Javascript to find a result depending on 3 differents paremeters without using a lot of "if" or "switch".

My case: I have 3 dropdown lists, each of them allow the user to chose a number between 0 and 5.

Having the 3 results, I would like to pick the corresponding result (in my case, redirecting to a specific URL).

Ex: The user chooses  2 0 4 -> specific url.

This is not really a "javascript" question but more a program logic question but keep in mind I need to do it in javascript.

I was thinking about a 3 dimensions table but can't figure out how to initiate and use it..

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are the rules to chose/generate the specific url ?

Comment: In my case there was no rules really, so as Kyle suggested I can make self the url according to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

Say you have a button to go to the url:  call it #my-button:

Have a click event that does something like:

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){
 base_url = 'http:www.xyz.com?sfdasf=' + $('#selctor1').val() + $('#selctor2').val() + $('#selctor3').val();

//Now execute
})
```

The idea is to build the url string using what exists in the selectors.  This of course depends on if the urls use the information in the selector dropdowns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's something I didn't think about but this could work well enough!
I just need to make a template to name my pages depending on my results but that would even make sense anyway.

Thanks a lot!